# Why does the display in Eclipse not support recursive functions in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have implemented a factorial function in Java in the Eclipse IDE.

```
public class Utilities {
   public static int factorial(int n) {
        int result;
    if (n <= 1) // base case
        return 1;
    else {
        result = (n * factorial(n - 1));
        return result;
    }
}
}
```

In the display in Eclipse, I inspect `Utilities.factorial(6)`. However, I get this error.

```
Utilities.factorial(6);
    Evaluation failed. Reason(s):
        Cannot perform nested evaluations.
```

Why does the display not support recursive calls? Is that the problem?

Comment: It works in the expression view while using the debugger, if you need a workaround.

Comment: If you replace `result = ` with `return` you can save 3 lines of code, btw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To return the answer, it must evaluate the expression, to do that it must evaluate the inner expression, to do that it must evaluate the inner expression, to do that it must evaluate the inner expression.

Generally when a debugger blows the stack (too many nested stack frames) people submit bugs to the development team that writes the debugger.  They fix the problem, by the only means known at this time: No recursion.

If you could evaluate how deep the stack needs to go without evaluating the expression in a nested manner, for any recursive expression; there's a shiny [Fields Medal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal) waiting for you (and probably a University ready to build a new building in your name).  This problem is related to [the Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), and unfortunately, with our computing model, it is known that the Halting Problem is unsolvable.

Answer (score 4):

### The Culprit: Recursion

Most IDEs will not do this sort of evaluation, it has nothing to do with Java and more to do with recursion.  Since Eclipse can't know how deep the recursion will go it doesn't even bother evaluating the expression, otherwise it could hang the JVM (if the recursion was buggy) or cause an 'out of heap' exception from which, in either case, would be hard to recover.

Have you tried smaller numbers for the sentinel, e.g. `Utilities.factorial(1)`?

Answer (score -1):

Unrelated:
If this is a method you actually want to use, recursion is not the way to go. As a bare minimum, re-write the function as an iterative one. Depending on your use case, you can use various approximations, such as [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) or [this one](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jmi-04-30.pdf).

Comment: Because it is faster not to keep track of stack traces.

Comment: Sounds like premature optimization. Do you know how many steps it will take before exceeding the value space of int?